# Crystal Reports - suppress subreport parameter prompts

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal report with several subreports linked on a common field - all working great. Now must add another, very complex, existing report as a new sub. This report's data source code stretches several pages. It also has over a dozen parameters which are further imbedded in numerous formula fields through out. That said, it runs fine and has a parameter that links with the main report. Unfortunately all the other parameter prompts is supremely annoying.

I've searched high and low for a method to accept default values without prompts but Crystal doesn't seem to accommodate that notion.

Revising the report to remove all the unneeded parameters would be extremely painful and simply not an option.

I'm hoping to find an alternate way to pass the parameter values to prevent the prompt. I'm aware of the SetParameterValue() method of the ReportDocument class but not sure how to use it. I've found examples of how to use it with C#, VS, ASP.net, etc., none of which work for an end user like myself.

Could the data source command itself be used?

Much thanks for any recommendations, guidance or thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Command Level prompts, you would never be able to change the prompt values with the CR Viewer.

If the report is supposed to be viewed in the CR Viewer and you need the functionality or changing prompt values, try this:

1) Remove Command Level prompts
2) Create the Data prompt in the report from the Field Explorer
3) Create a Record Selection formula like this:

{date_field} = {?Date_prompt}

under Report > Selection Formulas > Saved data

4) Save the report with data

Try this...

Comment: Thanks Jack. That sounds hopeful as a possible solution. I'll give it a try.

Comment: OK, give a feedback when you check it. @puckhead